# Remove button with ActionListener from JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Basically I have a class that extends JFrame, and I'm trying to have an ActionListener remove a button after another button has been clicked, it doesn't seem to be working...

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                System.out.println("Registered existing character click...");
                getContentPane().remove(loginButton);
                frame.remove(newAccountButton);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();

                //add(lookUp);
                //add(searchButton);
                bg.setIcon(rsLgn);
//                lookUp.requestFocus();
//                setComponentZOrder(searchButton, 0);
//                setComponentZOrder(lookUp, 0);


            }
        });
```

[image]
EDIT: Currently, the button is invisible, so I wouldn't *technically* know if it was removed or not, but the System.out.println is definitely still outputting the original message of "Registered existing character click..."

Comment: This sounds like you really want to use a CardLayout to swap views. I know that if this were my GUI and I wanted to vary the view of the GUI on state change, that's what I'd do.

Comment: Hm.... Maybe I hadn't thought about that, as I was already placing buttons via pixel locations... Should it automatically be removing a panel of the buttons then adding another of the new ones?

Comment: `"...as I was already placing buttons via pixel locations"` -- a common newbie mistake. While initially it might seem that the easiest way to create complex Swing GUI's is to place them with null layouts and absolute positioning, the more you do this, and more importantly, the more you have to **maintain** GUI's, the more you will come to see that this is the absolute worst way to create a GUI since GUI's thus created are rigid and difficult to change. Much better would be to use the layout managers to help position and size your components.

Comment: Well the problem, is I want to use a picture as the "background" and place buttons over buttons that are in the background, and the only way I saw to do it properly was with absolute positioning...

Comment: Also, I tried to add in CardLayout, but for some reason I'm not able to set the size/bounds of a JPanel to the size of my frame, I tried using `panel.setBounds(this.getBounds());` and it didn't work...

Comment: In response to your comment, I tried doing a grid, and since I needed to put them in spaces that weren't working... I had to go with absolute positioning... Example of what I had set up: http://puu.sh/i1KWr/7ae9a10e9b.jpg